# Find series $\arctan \frac{a-x}{a+x}$ near x=0

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find series $\arctan \frac{a-x}{a+x}$ near x=0 the radius of convergence $R$

I got

$\arctan \frac{a-x}{a+x} = \pi / 4 + \sum_{n =0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{a^{2n+1}}$

But what to do with $\pi/4$ (how to put it in sum?) and how to find $R$?
Or single member does not play role?

I suppose that $R = a^2$

Comment: If a power series is given by $$\frac{\pi}{4}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{\color{red}{(2n+1)}\,a^{2n+1}}$$ its radius of convergence is $|a|$ by the very **definition** of radius of convergence ($\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\ldots$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{a}+\tan^{-1} \frac{a-x}{a+x} &=
  \tan^{-1}
  \left(
   \frac{\frac{x}{a}+\frac{a-x}{a+x}}
        {1-\frac{x}{a} \frac{a-x}{a+x}}
  \right) \\ &=
  \tan^{-1} \frac{x(a+x)+a(a-x)}{a(a+x)-x(a-x)} \\ &=
  \tan^{-1} \frac{x^2+a^2}{a^2+x^2} \\ &=
  \frac{\pi}{4} \\
  \tan^{-1} \frac{a-x}{a+x} &= \frac{\pi}{4}-\tan^{-1} \frac{x}{a} \\
  &= \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{a}+\frac{x^3}{3a^3}-\ldots+
     \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)a^{2n-1}}+\ldots
\end{align*}

Using ratio test,

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}
\left|
  \frac{(2n-1)a^{2n-1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)a^{2n+1}x^{2n-1}}
\right|=
\frac{x^2}{a^2}<1$$

$$x^2<a^2$$

$$R=a$$